# How to customize android operating system of my smartphone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I'm wondering how can I customize android operating system in my smartphone? I have LG L90 D410 smartphone. It has Android KitKat 4.4.2.

Like we customize Windows 7 (for PC) by slipstreaming it using RT Se7en Lite or nLite software. We decide which software or updates we want to add or remove to/from the installation disc (iso file). Similarly we have nokia theme studio s40 for customizing symbian s40 nokia phones.

In the same way, do we have any Windows based software which can customize/configure Android operating system so that I can decide what apps will be bundled in the KitKat and what built-in apps (unnecessary factory apps) that I no longer need can be removed to save space and avoid cluttering. Is there any GUI based software available in the market which can enable us to tweak the android phone the way I want and put full hold on it?

**EDIT**

Ok guys; I am willing to root my phone from very beginning but don't know how and where to start on. My phone's warranty has already been expired so no need to worry about it. But you didn't tell me about any software or appropriate article though which I can start the process. I already knew the phone needs to be rooted before any tweaking. But how to and what's next. Any subject oriented stackexchange post will be very helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this XDA Developers subforum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-l90

That's the general discussion forum for your phone, and you can find lots of fun stuff there including mods, themes, guides to root and do other things, custom ROMs, kernels, and more. If you want to play with or change your operating system or its features in any way, XDA is the place to keep a lookout in. But make sure you read posts **thoroughly** to make sure that you know what you're doing and so that you don't end up breaking or bricking your phone.

As for your specific request, [this thread in the L90 forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2732311) will get your phone rooted quick and easy as long as you follow the instructions well. Make sure you get ADB and download all the files prior to starting the process, and also, please don't jump into it without *making a backup*.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for those links. I will look into them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've rooted your device,you can't absolutely remove built-in apps on your android phones,but you can simply disable them through settings>apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't remove the stock apps from your phone, you'll have to root it first.

But when you do, you'll be able to not only remove apps you don't want or need, but even always use the newest Android version (even if it isn't even officially supported from your device), install new, custom operating systems and much more like restricting permissions from apps you don't want to give them but still use them. I'd recommend it to you, although many manufacturers don't like that and void the warranty if you root your phone.

How exactly to do that is device-specific, you'll have to do some googling. And, if you decide to root, *always* make a full backup first! This way if you accidentally break anything, you'll be on the save side.

Comment: _always use the newest Android version_ - that is, when someone has developed one for your particular device. L90 does seem to have CM13 available for it ([link](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=w7)) which is a good sign.